# Unable to understand output of Math.min(0,-0)

Tags: java, min

Accordin to the following link, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_min_int.htm

In Math.min() method in java, If one argument is positive zero and the other is negative zero, the result is negative zero. But when i tried the statement
System.out.println(Math.min(0,-0));
i got the result 0(positive zero) . Should n't it be -0(negative zero) ? If not,then why?

Comment: The site blindly copied the text from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29, but from the wrong method. You're better off with the official documentation instead.

Answer (score 5):

The page you linked talks about the `int` version of `Math.min`, but it talks about several floating-point-only concepts, including infinity, NaN, and negative zero. It's an error in that page.

Integer types don't distinguish between positive and negative zero, so even if you do `System.out.println(-0);` without `min`, it will display `0`. Floating-point types `float` and `double` do have separate positive and negative zero values. If you add the `f` or `d` suffix to the values so they are of type `float` or `double`, you will get the negative zero result you expect:

```
System.out.println(Math.min(0f, -0f));
```

If you check the real documentation, you will see the difference between [`Math.min(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) and [`Math.min(float, float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-float-float-).